# ng model not updated in the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, modal-dialog

I have a modal launched from a directive (the modal contains a select option) 
I am unable to update the ngModel into my controller
Any help would be appreciated

Thank you very much

test.html

```
<div class="col-md-5">
               <select ng-model="noteSelected">
                      <option ng-selected="{{note == noteSelected}}" value="{{note }}" ng-repeat="note  in noteList">{{note }}</option>
               </select>           
               <button id="buttonOk" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
</div>
```

directive

```
link : function(scope, element, attr) {             
                    scope.openDialog = function() {                 
                            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                                templateUrl : 'partials/template/test.html',
                                controller : 'ModalInstance',
                                resolve : {
                                    infos: function() {
                                        return scope.infos;                                 
                                }
                            });
```

modal

```
cmcApp.controller('ModalInstance', [
        "$scope", "$modalInstance", "infos", 
        function($scope, $modalInstance, infos) {

$scope.noteList= infos.noteList;
$scope.ok = function() {
$scope.newNote = $scope.noteSelected ; //always undefined
          };
     }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time that you are assigning $scope.noteSelected to $scope.newNote it is undefined and you in fact do not seem to update it.

Try this:

add either a ng-change to your select:

html:

```
<select ng-model="noteSelected" ng-change="updateNewNote()">
```

and in your controller the function that assigns the value on change:

```
$scope.updateNewNote = function() {
  $scope.newNote = $scope.noteSelected ;
};
```

or add a watch in your controller that assigns the new value to $scope.newNote on change

```
$scope.$watch('noteSelected', function(selected) {
    $scope.newNote = selected
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help . I have tried both solutions you provided but nothing work ( still undefined ) :( . I don't know why the ng model is not accessible in the controller

Comment: Here it seems to work just fine. Can you provide a plunker, codepen or jsfiddle to debug?

Comment: It's difficult for me to implement this on a jsfiddle because i have various modules related ( directives , controllers , modal, template etc..) that are difficult to simulate . Anyway , your solution works if i add the ngModel into the ng-change like this "ng-change="updateNewNote(noteSelected)" so it's fine . Thank you very much